# TypeScript: No error for incorrect function return value

Tags: typescript

I expected an error for this buggy function (returning an object where an array is expected), but TypeScript did not raise an error:

```
function foo(bar: boolean, baz: any): string[] {
  return bar ? baz : {};
}
```

It seems this only occurs when the other ternary branch returns `any` [1]. Regardless of the `any`, shouldn't TypeScript be able to detect the error on the other branch?

---

[1] I know that `baz` shouldn't be typed as `any`. This example is derived from an actual project that does not exactly adhere to best practices like this. Also, `unknown` didn't exist when this code was written.

Comment: A `return` can only have one type, and `typeof bar` widens that type to `any`, so `typeof {}` coerces to `any` which then coerces to `string[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When doing type inference, TypeScript picks the *best common type* ([docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html)). In your example, the compiler has to infer the result type of the conditional expression.¹ The best common type for `any` and `object` is `any`. Since `any` matches anything, there's no warning.

If you use `if` instead...

```
function foo(foo: boolean, bar: any): string[] {
    if (foo) {
        return bar;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

...the compiler doesn't have to infer the type of the conditional expression, and reports an error on `return {}`.

---

¹ `? :` is the *conditional operator*. It's ***a*** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands, just as a unary operator accepts one operand and a binary operator accepts two), and for the moment it's JavaScript's (and TypeScript's) only ternary operator, but in theory someday there could be another ternary operator added...

Comment: That is an interesting insight, and makes sense now. Thanks for the quick clarification!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is `bar` is of type `any`. The type of a ternary operation would be a union of both possible result types. In this case that would mean `any | {}`. But the rules for how unions are resolved dictate that if `any` is part of the union the whole union just becomes `any` (this makes sense, if something is `any` (which is any possible type) or anything else, it can be anything so that would be `any`).

This would be an error:

```
function foo(foo: boolean, bar: string[]): string[] {
  return foo ? bar : {}; // Type 'string[] | {}' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
}
```

**Note** To avoid such errors, `any` should generally be avoided, as of 3.0 you should prefer `unknown`, this would be an error

```
function foo(foo: boolean, bar: unknown): string[] {
  return foo ? bar : {}; // Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
}
```

Comment: Ah neat. Finally there is a better type for `any`.

Comment: Ooooh, neat about v3's `unknown`.